# Convocar una función de un Controller dentro de otra

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una función que genera un documento PDF con datos de un usuario.

```
public function exportar(User $usuario){    
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.curriculo', compact('usuario'));
        return $pdf->download('Curriculo de '.$usuario->name.' '.$usuario->second_name.".pdf");
    }
```

Esto generara un PDF con los datos de ese usuario.
Ahora, quiero crear una función que genere un PDF de cada uno de los usuarios.

```
public function fichaje(){
        $usuarios=User::all();
        if(count($usuarios)==0)
            return back()->with('message',['danger','No hay ningun usuario en nuestra base de datos']);
        else{
            foreach($usuarios as $usuario)
               return $this->exportar($usuario);
        }
    }
```

El problema es que a la hora de la verdad solo genera el PDF del primer usuario. Esto se tiene que deber a que uso un return al llamar al metodo, pero si no se lo pongo o pruebo a asignarlo a una variable no funcionara. ¿Como hago para que se ejecute este metodo tantas veces como me haga falta?

Edito: Al final lo que he hecho es que se mostrara un unico PDF con la lista de usuarios.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
<html lang="es">
<body>
    @forelse($usuarios as $usuario)
        @include('pdf.datos_personales')
    @empty
    Se ha producido un error...
    @endforelse
</body>
</html>
```

Y dentro de datos_personales.blade.php:

```
<?php
    $formaciones=$usuario->formacion;
    $idiomas=$usuario->idiomas;
    $experiencias=$usuario->experiencias;
?>

<font size="17" style="display: inline;">Datos del usuario</font> <img style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" align="right" src="{{url($usuario->ruta())}}"/>
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Residencia</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>DNI</th>
                <th>Vehiculo</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $usuario->name }} {{ $usuario->second_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $usuario->direccion }} ({{ $usuario->localidad }}, {{ $usuario->provincia }})</td>
                <td>{{ $usuario->telefono }}</td>
                <td>{{ $usuario->dni }}</td>
                <td>
                    @if($usuario->vehiculo)
                        Es poseedor de vehiculo propio
                    @else
                        No posee vehiculo propio
                    @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php
        $forma=count($formaciones);
        $exp=count($experiencias);
        $idi=count($idiomas);
    ?>

    <hr>

    @if($forma>0)
        <h3>Cursos realizados</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Grado</th>
                    <th>Centro</th>
                    <th>Finalización</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @forelse($formaciones as $formacion)
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$formacion->titulo}}</td>
                        <td>{{$formacion->grado}}</td>
                        <td>{{$formacion->centro}}</td>
                        <td>
                            @if($formacion->finalizacion)
                                {{$formacion->anyio_finalizacion}}
                            @else
                                No
                            @endif
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            @empty
                Se ha producido un error
            @endforelse
        </table>
    @else
        <h3>No ha hecho ningun curso formativo</h3>
    @endif

    <hr>

    @if($idi>0)
        <h3>Idiomas estudiados</h3>
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Idioma</th>
                    <th>Nivel de habla</th>
                    <th>Nivel de escritura</th>
                    <th>Titulo oficial</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @forelse($idiomas as $idioma)
                <tbody>
                    <td>{{$idioma->idioma}}</td>
                    <td>{{$idioma->nivel_hablado}}</td>
                    <td>{{$idioma->nivel_escrito}}</td>
                    <td>{{$idioma->titulo_oficial}}</td>
                </tbody>
            @empty
                Se ha producido un error
            @endforelse
        </table>
    @else
        <h3>No ha estudiado ningun idioma</h3>
    @endif

    <hr>

    @if($exp>0)
        <h3>Experiencia Laboral</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Puesto</th>
                <th>Función realizada</th>
                <th>Empresa</th>
                <th>Sector</th>
                <th>Fecha de inicio</th>
                <th>Fecha de finalización</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @forelse($experiencias as $experiencia)
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->puesto}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->funcion_realizada}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->empresa}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->sector_empresa}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->mes_anyo_inicio}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->mes_anyo_fin}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        @empty
            Se ha producido un error
        @endforelse
        </table>
    @else
        <h3>No tiene experiencia laboral</h3>
    @endif
```

Sin embargo, no es un sistema perfecto. Noto algunos fallos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer usuario de la lista no tiene este error, por lo que diria que el fallo se relaciona con el momento de crear otra página.

Comment: **No podras**, lo que te recomiendo es hacer el foreach de usuarios en tu vista(view), y exportar un solo PDF con varias paginas.

Comment: @Shassain Así hice al final. Aunque aun noto ciertos fallos. Edito mi comentario.

Comment: Debes de colocar saltos de pagina en la documentacion de tu libreria deberia de existir la forma.